# Copy() image url give me a different result as open in it Firefox > Save as

Tags: php, image, copy

I have a Php problem. I need to dynamically save Php generated image.
For exemple this one :

http://www.colissimo.fr/portail_colissimo/imageio?styleBold=true&width=75&id=17805280_date_1

When I open it in a web browser and do Save As, no problem. But when I do it from a php call, The image is correctly saved, but the text is wrong (in my case "????") :

```
copy('http://www.colissimo.fr/portail_colissimo/imageio?styleBold=true&width=75&id=17805280_date_1', 'my_pic.png');
```

Do you know how to do to have the image with the correct text?

Comment: When I open that image in my browser, the text is still `?????`.

Comment: Here a screenshot from my post  : http://i.imgur.com/q1AvnFc.png (Precision : I'm not connected to the website)

Comment: Your image creator works, you create a valid PNG file. Something is going wrong in the logic that makes the string. Check your logs for errors.

Comment: Ok I find the problem, there is a test on the Cookie... it will be hard to fix that !